# MVC design pattern. How does View fit it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, design-patterns, uiviewcontroller

I have a questions about the Model-View-Controller design Pattern.  I understand the model holds the data.  I also understand the Controller (View Controllers) implement the logic of the app.  For example, if the UIPicker wheel selects row 4, then the View Controller can ask the Model for the 4th object stored in the Model's array.  I'm having trouble understanding were the "Views" fit in.  I would think that that nib / storyboard file would be classified as the "View".  However every view requires that a View Controller be connected to wire up all the outlets to the view.  How am I suppose to keep the View and the View Controller separated?  Should I wire all the outlets to the "View Class" and then in my View Controller reference my "View" class when implementing the logic of those outlets?  Maybe I just need an example where the View and the View Controller handle different tasks.  Because otherwise the an extra "View" class doesn't seem to make sense.  Is the View of MVC referring to a View Class?  How or why would I want to have this View Class separated from my View Controller class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A view's job is to display data and to report events.

The controller's job is to coordinate communication between views and models.

The data's job is store data and also to provide business logic around that data.

You asked:

> I'm having trouble understanding were the "Views" fit in.

In your example, the `UIPickerView` is the view.

In iOS/OSX, a view controller is just the controller of MVC. It just so happens that a view controller also contains an empty view container that you can add all of the other views to. But there is still a clear separation of MVC in iOS/OSX.

All of the classes like `UIButton`, `UIPickerView`, `UITableView`, etc. represent the view. A view controller's job is to provide those views with data from data models as well as respond to events from those views giving you a chance to update other views and the data models.

You also stated:

> However every view requires that a View Controller be connected to wire up all the outlets to the view. How am I suppose to keep the View and the View Controller separated?

They are separate. If you add a `UITableView`, that is a separate view. You connect it to a class so that class can implement the data source and delegate methods. That class is a controller class. It is common for this controller class to be a view controller but it doesn't have to be. You can write all kinds of custom view classes that are independent of any specific view controller (or generic controller). But eventually that view class needs to be hooked up to a [view] controller class so data and events can be processed properly.

You asked:

> How or why would I want to have this View Class separated from my View Controller class?

Look at `UITableViewController`. This is a clear example of the separation but it is provided in a fairly neat package. You actually have a separate `UITableView` class which is the view. This view is responsible for rendering the view and gathering user interaction. It is the actual table view controller that provides the data to the view and handles the user events from the view.

You can add `UITableView` views to any view. This is a fully reusable view component. Each controller you hook up to a table view can provide any appropriate data and properly handle user interactions.

Comment: wow thank you for thorough answer!  I feel like this is the most iOS specific answer that answers root of my question.  You say that View Controller are controller objects (and not a blend of controllers and views objects).  You say views are the hierarchy of objects on the blank view that comes with storyboard / xib file.  I think I'm was thinking a "View" object didn't exist if there wasn't a specific separate class for it.  It seems many times that the "View" object wouldn't require a separate class.  However certain views (like table views) require view classes (like table cell view).

Comment: Every widget you drag onto a storyboard or view controller is a separate view class. This is far more obvious when you do everything in code.

Comment: thanks!  This answer definitely gets a check mark.  That clears a lot up.  No disrespect to the the other people who answered, but I think I should have stated that I'm working in xcode for iOS development.  I was surprised term view controller was a mystery to some - but I guess MVC applies to different languages that don't use the view controller objects.

Comment: MVC is a general design pattern that is independent of any programming language. Various frameworks written in various different languages provide support for the MVC pattern.

Comment: Great explanation Maddy!! But, I would like to know more that the 'Model' part which is used to store data. How to design these models? What kind of class it should be ideally?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I will try to sort things out a bit.

The pattern is called Model-View-Controller, thus clearly separating the Model, the View and the Controller. As you correctly pointed out, the ViewController puts things together (from the View and the Controller :) and actually the ViewController breaks the strong MVC pattern. The good news is: you don't have to separate the view and the controller if you are using a ViewController (guess why it is named that way?).

Now my nooby explanation of why the design is what it is:

When you strongly separate the View and the Controller you basically earn credit points for good design. However, as it turns out, the two of them are not as separated as we'd like them to be. Different GUI representations usually do require a different view implementation as well as an adaption of the controller that controls the forwarding of the Model to the GUI, e.g. plain text display on the console vs. drawing on a bitmap. In the first case, your Controller would pass a string to the view to be rendered, in the second it would also need to set some coordinates in order to get the text rendered into the right place. Consequently, your controller is going to change quite often.

The ideal case would be to implement the model, and the controller and simply provide views for anything that anybody is ever going to see in real live. However, in real life situations, the controller will most likely adapt to the view while leaving the model alone. Thus the design decision to combine the view and the controller to a ViewController which contains a particular view and knows how to use it is just a reasonable way to go.

Comment: thanks.  If I understand this correctly, when working with View Controllers, most likely I would be working with a Model - ViewController pattern instead of a M-V-C pattern.  This could be good or could be bad depending on the complexity of my app.  So maybe if I wanted to go with the M-V-C pattern, when dragging a ViewController object onto my storyboard, I would change it's class to a custom View class instead.  I will make another class for my model and another class for my controller.  This will keep things clean and I won't be tempted to dirty up my design pattern with a ViewController.

Comment: @tereško no there is not. However, as the original question suggests the topic is iOS/OSX Development (thats where the ViewControllers are from) and I just tried to explain why the Designers have chosen that concept while propagating MVC.

Comment: @RyanBittorf Exactly. If you can manage to clearly separate the controllers from your views - go for it. However, bear in mind that the "ViewController" idiom is deeply nested within Cocoa development - thus the VC's do a lot of things you otherwise will have to implement manually (rotating the view for instance...)

Comment: @tereško And actually, if you'd read carefully enough, you would have encountered a clarification of the issue in my second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you understand is completely wrong.

The core principle behind MVC design pattern is [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). You separate model layer from presentation layer and (in the presentation layer) you separate views from controller.

Each of there pars have a different responsibility:

- model layer contains all of the business logic. That includes interaction with storage, domain logic and application logic.
- view is responsible for UI logic. In context of Web this means, that view deals with creating response for the user
- controller is the part that takes the user input and , based on that, changes the sate of model layer and current view.

---

There are a lot of **misconception** about MVC that people tend to perpetuate. For example:

1. Some will insist that views are dumb templates. They are not.

   Views in MVC design pattern are fully functional instance which deal might or might not use multiple template to generate the response.
2. There are no "models". Model is a layer, that consists of multiple different groups of classes, each with specific task. Same way as there are no "presentation" objects for presentation layer
3. Controllers do not send data from model layer to views. Controller only changes the state of other parts of triad. The view instances themselves request what they need from model layer.

Comment: You should bear in mind that the question is not solely about the MVC pattern. It it is about the application of the MVC pattern in a real-world context (namely iOS - read the text!). It might be tagged wrong, but use your common sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer your question let's break down MVC - Model, View, Controller. What goes where?

The **Model** is typically considered the "do something" layer. This holds the business logic and data logic. Your model should be FAT, not SKINNY, meaning you should have a lot of your code in the Model.

The **Controller**, I consider the "response" layer. This is where you decide what to return to the user, whether that's a View or other type of response, such as JSON (particularly useful in RESTful responses). You can use the Model as well, but you shouldn't be building too much logic into the Controller itself. You should have a SKINNY controller.

The **View** is largely the markup for the page - the HTML along with other markup for getting access to the model - this depends on the framework you're using. My experience is with MVC .NET, so I'll go with that. Mixed in with the HTML you'll access the Model elements. There shouldn't be any real logic in the View, but you can do things like (using Razor syntax)

```
<div>@foreach person in Model.Users{
    <p>@person.FullName</p>
}
</div>
```

So you can see that the View can have some "display logic" (like, loop over people and get FullName) but that's all you should really have there.

Here's a quick slideshow that explains more about MVC, including why your initial explanation of "Model holds the data, Controller holds the logic" actually isn't true: http://www.slideshare.net/damiansromek/thin-controllers-fat-models-proper-code-structure-for-mvc

The MVC Design Pattern doesn't include anything called "ViewController", that's coming from somewhere else.

Comment: James - I'm building iOS apps in Objective C using Xcode.  When building the views graphically the objects used are called view controllers.  There are also table view controllers, etc.  When starting up a project, you presented with a blank view controller and a view controller class.  Everyone teaches building iOS using view controllers.  These people also preach about M-V-C.  When demonstrating building apps, things blend together with the view controllers

Comment: After a brief googling, it appears that ViewControllers are sort of "enhanced controllers" that you can use to manage multiple Views. I must point out that this is still NOT a part of the traditional MVC model, which is what I posted above, this is something that's different. MVC means many things to many people, but the standard accepted way was what I explained.